# move to trash on ~/.Trash folder

Tags: finder, bug, shortcut-menu

Why finder application is showing move to trash on ~/.Trash folder? If you will click on move to trash it will show an indefinite progress indicator that will never ends.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It has it on my 10.7.4 too so it seems to just be a (relatively minor) bug. Stack Exchange is not an issue tracker though... I'm voting to close this question since it cannot really be answered.

Comment: Are you trying to move  ~/.Trash to itself?

Answer (score 4):

Almost all Mac users won't ever see hidden files and folders in Finder. There's no need for Apple to hide actions on stuff which is already hidden in the first place.

Experienced users like you, who know how to show hidden folders in Finder, should also know that moving the Trash into itself is a weird idea.